# How to make React functional component recreate callback function and read updated props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a very simple functional component in React. When this component is rendered by the parent component, initially `myList` is an empty array, and then eventually when it finishes loading, it is a list with a bunch of items.

The problem is, the value of `myList` inside `onSearchHandler` never gets updated, it's always `[]`.

```
const MyComponent = ({ myList }) => {
  const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState(myList);

  console.log(myList); // <<< This outputs [], and later [{}, {}, {}] which is expected.

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredList(myList);
  }, [myList]);

  const onSearchHandler = (searchText) => {
    console.log(myList); /// <<< When this function is called, this always outputs []
    const filteredItems = myList.filter(item =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
    );
    setFilteredList(filteredItems);
  };

  return <AnotherComponent items={filteredList} onSearch={onSearchHandler} />
};
```

Is there a way to force onSearchHandler to re-evaluate the value of myList? What would be the recommended approach for this sort of operation?

Comment: The right way would be to fix `AnotherComponent` - do you have control over its code?

Comment: I do not, unfortunately. What is "wrong" there, though? (out of curiosity)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `AnotherComponent` does not take into consideration the changed prop - this should be considered to be a bug in `AnotherComponent`. Ideally, you'd fix it so that the changed prop gets used properly. Eg, just for an example, maybe it's doing

```
const [searchHandler, setSearchHandler] = useState(props.onSearch);
```

and failing to observe prop changes as it should. Or, for another random example, this could happen if the listener prop gets passed to an `addEventListener` when the component mounts but again doesn't get checked for changes and removed/reattached.

If you can't fix `AnotherComponent`, you can use a ref for `myList` in addition to the prop:

```
const MyComponent = ({ myList }) => {
    const myListRef = useRef(myList);
    useEffect(() => {
        myListRef.current = myList;
        setFilteredList(myList);
    }, [myList]);
    const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState(myList);
    const onSearchHandler = (searchText) => {
        const filteredItems = myListRef.current.filter(item =>
            item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
        );
        setFilteredList(filteredItems);
    };
```

It's ugly, but it might be your only option here.

Comment: This only works in the first try, because the `myList` parameter `setFilteredList` receives has been filtered. Inside the search handler I need to access the original `myList`, which contains all items.

Comment: Oh, I see, you have multiple separate lists. Guess you'll have to use a ref.

Comment: I found out that the problem is that `AnotherComponent` uses `lodash.debounce` to call the `onSearch` handler. So yeah, I guess in this case `useRef` is the only solution.

Comment: If this is from an open-source library, sounds like it would benefit from a pull request, it's probably a pretty trivial fix. Is its link shareable?

Comment: It's an internal package managed by my company, but not by me/my team. I've reported it to the responsible team. What would be the trivial fix for it?

Comment: Hard to say for sure without seeing the code. It could be something along the lines of `useEffect(() => { clearTimeout(timeoutIdRef.current); timeoutIdRef.current = /* set new timeout */ }, [props.onSearch]);`. Probably takes less than 10 lines and 10 minutes of coding